# Php MySql query get 3 row or less with same user

Tags: php, mysql

can someone help to figure it out this is my query in php function :
So i always got $item->dummy_1 = 1 or all items
i need to get $item->dummy_1 = 1 the next $item->dummy_1 = 2 etc ....

> $query = "SELECT a.*"
>
> ```
>       .",@num := IF( @type = a.created_by, @num +1, 1 ) AS dummy_1, @type := a.created_by AS dummy_2, @num AS row_number"
>
>       ." FROM ".TABLE_ITEM." AS a"
>
>       ." LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_CATEGORY_ITEM." AS b ON a.id = b.item_id"
>
>       .($join ? $join : "")
>
>       ." WHERE a.application_id = ".(int) $application_id
>
>       ." AND b.category_id ".(is_array($category_id) ? " IN (".implode(",", $category_id).")" : " = ".(int) $category_id)
>
>       ." AND ".$this->app->user->getDBAccessString($user)
>
>       .($published == true ? " AND a.state = 1"
>
>       ." AND (a.publish_up = ".$null." OR a.publish_up <= ".$now.")"
>
>       ." AND (a.publish_down = ".$null." OR a.publish_down >= ".$now.")": "") 
>
>       ." GROUP BY a.id, row_number having row_number < 4 "
>
>       ." ORDER BY a.created_by DESC"//. (!$ignore_order_priority ? " " : "") . $order
>
>       .(($limit ? " LIMIT ".(int) $offset.",".(int) $limit : ""));                    
>
>   return $this->app->table->item->_queryObjectList($query);
> ```

Comment: Can you please add this function _queryObjectList here?

Comment: >protected function _queryObjectList($query) {

  >// query database
  >$result = $this->database->query($query);

  >// fetch objects and execute init callback
  >$objects = array();
  >while ($object = $this->database->fetchObject($result, $this->class)) {
   >$objects[$object->{$this->key}] = $this->_initObject($object);
  }

  >$this->database->freeResult($result);
  return $objects;
 }